# Modify Shipping/handling charges during checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, shipping-methods

I am new to magento. I have module which is to Modify Shipping/handling charges during checkout.

**Ex:** If Customer select any UPS/FedEx/USPS services it will be populate/add from Cart/Checkout summery but no need to add/apply charges (no need to apply Shipping Charges).

Any Idea,Suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: in which you want to modify the shipping charge, please elaborate your question so that i will help you

Comment: @AmitKamboj, I want to select Shipping Service but do not want to add shipping charge to order total from checkout page.

Comment: You can make a shipping method any name by a custom module and set the price of it as you want to add, and from available.phtml file in checkout/onpages/shippingmethod get that shipping method and checked it by default. Hope this will help you. if you need any custom shipping mehtod i will going to post a ans from which you get a shipping method.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this you find a correct way:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881621/how-to-get-all-available-shipping-methods-programmatically-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

First declare an observer for the sales_quote_collect_totals_before event.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <observers>
                    <your_module>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
                    </your_module>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then, in the observer, adjust the handling type and fee configuration for each carrier in the corresponding store model.

```
public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();

    // Check your customer attribute of choice here instead of the customer id
    if ($quote->getCustomer()->getId()) {

        $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
        $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);
        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {

            // F for fixed, P for percentage
            $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_type", 'F');

            // 0 for no fee, otherwise fixed of percentage value
            $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_fee", '1');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the configuration changes are not saved, they are only valid during the request

Comment: I think this is for Fixed right, I tried this yester day i'm not getting. Ex: If i select UPS Ground Shipping services it should be add checkout page but do not want to add shipping charge to order total. how Can I do? Any Idea?

Comment: So ultimately you want free shipping for ground UPS?

Comment: Yah! But Order must have existing the selected Shipping method (no need to add/include charges).

Comment: This may be what you need
>http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-boosting-sales-by-offering-free-shipping

Comment: Actually I saw this earlier. Actually in my module have 2 shipping methods is there 1) Normal Shipping 2) Third party. When select 2 All shipping services will showing except charges. if I add No need to apply charges. If Select 1 normal procedure as megento have this.

Comment: Then you should add custom attribute to your method, and on the basis of that you should update shipping price programmatically

Comment: shipping Method K. Which method I should rewrite? it (totals) will reflect Order review Section on Checkout page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14945/discussion-between-tbi-infotech-and-magento-nav).

Comment: @TBIInfotech Could you pls help me with my post regard observer https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/285128/57334