# How to remove handling fees if customer select pick from store?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am using [extra fees extension](https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee), if customer choose shipping method : **Pick from store** how to remove Handling fees(extra fees extension).

> What event used to check if customer chooses to pick from store in
>   checkout page, if customer chooses to pick from store how to remove or
>   hide handling fees.

If i use https://stackoverflow.com/a/40486717/11697039  what is my event.

[image]

Comment: Please check first admin panel/store/configuration/shipping Method/pick from store method and check to handle fee and remove handling fee, save configuration and check. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee/blob/master/app/code/local/Voronoy/ExtraFee/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Fee/Rule.php

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('voronoy_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        parent::collect($address);
        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        $shipping_method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

        /* Flat Rate Condition Start*/
        if($shipping_method != 'flatrate_flatrate'):
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
            $this->_calculator->reset($address);

            $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
            if (!count($items)) {
                return $this;
            }

            $this->_calculator->init($store->getWebsiteId(), $quote->getCustomerGroupId(), $quote->getCouponCode());
            $this->_calculator->initTotals($items, $address);

            $items = $this->_calculator->sortItemsByPriority($items);
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        $this->_calculator->process($child);
                        $this->_addAmount($child->getExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                        $this->_addBaseAmount($child->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->_calculator->process($item);
                    $this->_addAmount($item->getExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                    $this->_addBaseAmount($item->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                }
            }
            $this->_calculator->prepareDescription($address);
        endif;
        / Flat Rate Condition End /
    }
```

Thanks : https://community.magento.com

Answer (score 2):

Take a look https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee/blob/master/app/code/local/Voronoy/ExtraFee/Block/Sales/Order/Totals/Rule.php

Check to see if the shipping method matches your local pickup method and exit the function. So instead of trying to remove the fee, you prevent it from been added. (Keep in mind that you should rewrite this class or try another acceptable way of making changes without directly editing this extension)

```
/**
 * Add this total to parent
 */
public function initTotals()
{
    /* start custom code */

    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod() === 'local_pickup') {
        return $this;
    }
    /* end custom code */

    if ((float) $this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleAmount() <= 0) {
        return $this;
    }
    if ($this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleDescription()) {
        $discountLabel = $this->__('%s (%s)', Mage::helper('voronoy_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel(),
            $this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleDescription());
    } else {
        $discountLabel = Mage::helper('voronoy_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel();
    }
    ....
```

Comment: I just created new observer, i am stick with condition https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/ea4b46ecec6f3fbb2ce395b5688dcb6b

Comment: @zus... not sure what you are trying to accomplish, the quickest way to accomplish your goal would be to add you logic around the area where it adds the fee.

Comment: Everything working fine, I need to add small feature, how to set extra fees on order grant total permanently, if i go to check order in back-end the extra fees not available https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPfap.png @Renon Stewart